# Using multiple database helpers in Android OrmLite

Tags: android, ormlite

My app uses two databases. To handle these databases I have created two `DatabaseHelper` classes, say class `X` and class `Y`.

I use the respective `getHelper()` methods to fetch the required database helper.

But when the initial helper is `X` and I need `Y`, I use this following code:

```
OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
dbHelper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, Y.class)
```

And I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Helper class was class X but is trying to be reset to class Y
```

I know that in OrmLite we can use a single instance of the helper with 1 database connection, and I don't think I am violating that rule. Can anyone help here, please?

Comment: If you look into class _OpenHelperManager_, you'll find that method `getHelper()` is preventing you from using two _DatabaseHelper_ classes extending from _OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper_. How so? The first time you call `getHelper()`, it calls `innerSetHelperClass()`, to keep a reference to the _DatabaseHelper_ class used as second parameter (your `Y.class`) in a static field. So next time you call it, it will detect if you are trying to call `getHelper()` passing it a different class other than the _DatabaseHelper_ class that you used the first time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that calling `OpenHelperManager.release()` or `OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper()` won't reset the value of this static field. Neither will `OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperClass(DifferentHelper.class)` do, since it calls `innerSetHelperClass()` too, which is the method preventing the value of the static field storing the former _DatabaseHelper_ class from being changed once it's been set.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are reusing the same variable dbHelper for both classes (class X and Y) but the type of dbHelper is not a parent class of X and Y. I would need to see more of your code, but it seems that this error has nothing to do with ormlite. You can either:

- Use a separate variable per helper (you will have some logic anyway to decide which database you want to access).
- Create an abstract parent class for classes X and Y and change the type of dbHelper to that.

Btw, here you can see an [example of using two databases with ormlite for android](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-examples/tree/master/android/HelloAndroidTwoDbs).

Comment: It seems the example you posted is not working properly. When I try to open the second database and execute `queryForAll()`, the primary key field is not detected and every object fills their fileds with the value of the next field in the query. For example, if my `MyStoredObject` has fields A, B and C, and A is the primary key, when I execute `queryForAll()` in the second helper I get `MyStoredObjects` where field A is loaded with B value, B is loadede with C value and C is set to the default value for its type of data.